# User Control Property Doesnt accept DynamicResource value

Tags: wpf

usercontrol.vb file

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Orion_Magnetics_Ascend.StrategicAlliance

Public Class usrValueSet

    Public WriteOnly Property LabelPropertyValueSet() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            lblValueSetsName.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

usercontrol.xaml file

```
<UserControl x:Class="usrValueSet"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="lblValueSetsName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

user control used like below on sample page

```
<local:usrValueSet x:Name="TFR_uvsCurrentLimitingFusePanelRating" Master="CurrentLimitingFusePanelRating" LabelPropertyValueSet="{DynamicResource TFR_tbRating}"   MaxTextLength="25"></local:usrValueSet>
```

if you can see above "LabelPropertyValueSet" i have assigned dynamic resource to it

but it gives me error

> A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'LabelPropertyValueSet' property of type 'usrValueSet'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

like above..

please anybody know how to assign dynamic resources to usercontrol property...?

Comment: The error is there for a reason, it tells you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

usercontrol.vb file you need change following things need to change make this property 
DependencyProperty and do following changes

```
Public Shared ReadOnly MyBorderBackgroundProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelPropertyValueSet", GetType(String), GetType(usrValueSet), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnBackChanged))

        Private Shared Sub OnBackChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
            Dim sender = DirectCast(d, usrValueSet)
            sender.lblValueSetsName.Text = e.NewValue
            'lblValueSetsName.Text = e.NewValue
            ' Put a breakpoint here
        End Sub


    Public WriteOnly Property LabelPropertyValueSet() As String
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                SetValue(MyBorderBackgroundProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property
```

after that you can assign dynamicresource value to usercontrol property
like below

```
  <local:usrValueSet x:Name="TFR_uvsExpulsionFusePanelRating" Master="ExpulsionFusePanelRating"  LabelPropertyValueSet="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TFR_tbRating}" MaxTextLength="25"></local:usrValueSet>
```